# C++ Maya - Getting mesh vertices from frame and subframe

Tags: c++, 3d, maya, mesh

I'm writing a mesh deformer plugin that gets info about the mesh from past frames to perform some calculations. In the past, to get past mesh info, I did the following

```
MStatus MyClass::deform(MDataBlock& dataBlock, MItGeometry& itGeo, 
        const MMatrix& localToWorldMatrix, unsigned int index)
{

    MFnPointArrayData fnPoints;


    //... other init code


    MPlug meshPlug = nodeFn.findPlug(MString("inputMesh"));

    // gets the mesh connection from the previous frame
    MPlug meshPositionPlug = meshPlug.elementByLogicalIndex(0);

    MObject objOldMesh;

    meshPositionPlug.getValue(objOldMesh);

    fnPoints.setObject(objOldMesh);
    // previous frame's vertices
    MPointArray oldMeshPositionVertices = fnPoints.array();


    // ... calculations


    return MS::kSuccess;
}
```

If I needed more than one frame I'd run for-loops over logical indices and repeat the process. Since creating this however, I've found that the needs of my plugin can't just get past frames but also frames in the future as well as **subframes (between integer frames)**. Since my current code relies on elementByLogicalIndex() to get past frame info and that only takes unsigned integers, and the 0th index refers to the previous frame, I can't get subframe information. I haven't tried getting future frame info yet but I don't think that's possible either.

How do I query mesh vertex positions in an array for past/future/sub-frames? Is my current method inflexible and, if so, how else could I do this?

Comment: There is really no good way of doing this. Your really in the deep end of maya an your about to throw nearly the entire maya pipe to the wolves. Ive experimented with using a loop node, this is sane however the normal DG eval will cleans this up so you need to manage quite a bit of mayas system yourself which is not so nice. Entire maya DG is working under the presumption that frames do not depend on other frames. But yes its possible to do you just end up with a dnamic simulation and loose the benefits of keyframing.

Comment: In this instance, losing keyframing isn't a problem. If no other way exists then I'm fine with going in a full-simulation route. That said, can you please recommend a learning resource or class/es in the documentation that would suit my current needs?

Comment: No the docs specifically think your not doing this. Bake the data down its most sane starting point.

Comment: what about caching the first pass into a cache node then generating the second pass from that? It would render the whole thing free of paradoxes which this otherwise seems like it would be riddled with...

Comment: I had the same thought - I've only been working on alembic caches from the outset so I basically am already doing this. My issue is that some of the caches have fast, sub-frame movement that my plug isn't taking advantage of, which is producing inaccurate results

Answer (score 0):

So, the "intended" way to accomplish this is with an [MDGContext](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_d_g_context_html), either with an [MDGContextGuard](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_d_g_context_guard_html), or with the versions of [MPlug.asMObject](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-SDK/cpp_ref/class_m_plug.html#ac1dfdf3c30ce6b6e578a65ae94890a51) that explicitly take a context (though these are deprecated).

Having said that - in the past when I've tried to use MDGContexts to query values at other times, I've found them either VERY slow, unstable, or both.  So use with caution. It's possible that things will work better if, as you say, you're dealing purely with objects coming straight from an alembic mesh.  However, if that's the case, you may have better luck reading the cache path from the node, and querying through the alembic API directly yourself.